# How do I install the build dependencies for Android?

Tags: 10.10, apt, build, package-management, 32-bit

I'm trying build the Android source using these packages.  ButI am getting this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 lib32ncurses5-dev ia32-libs x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32readline5-dev lib32z-dev
[sudo] password for asdf: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libc6-dev-i386
E: Unable to locate package lib32ncurses5-dev
E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs
E: Unable to locate package lib32readline5-dev
E: Unable to locate package lib32z-dev
```

I tried to download & install say libc6-dev-i386 debian package form [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick-updates/libc6-dev-i386). But when I double click on the .deb file Ubuntu Software Manager says wrong architecture 'amd64'.

(My OS: 32-bit Ubuntu 10.10 (updated), Processor: AMD phenom II 64-bit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the android.com page is a little out of date.  There are a lot of different workarounds that are floating around the net.  I'll try to summarize what worked for me.

Two helpful, if imperfect, pages are located here:

[crashcourse.ca](http://www.crashcourse.ca/wiki/index.php/Android_on_Ubuntu_10.04#Building_Android_in_its_entirety)
[wildartist](http://www.wildartist.org/archives/1178)

First, it looks like you'll probably want to use `java6` and not `java5`, judging by [some of the group threads](http://groups.google.com/group/android-building/tree/browse_frm/month/2010-07/47f5cd36168b5e33?rnum=161&_done=/group/android-building/browse_frm/month/2010-07?&pli=1)  . So if you see java5 in instructions, know that you'll need to substitute in either the sun java6 or open java 6.

Here are the packages I needed for my 32-bit system:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf libsdl-dev libesd0-dev libwxgtk2.6-dev build-essential zip curl libncurses5-dev zlib1g-dev openjdk-6-jdk ant gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

After those are in place, build `repo` :

```
sudo curl http://android.git.kernel.org/repo -o /usr/local/bin/repo   
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/repo
```

Then in your build directory:

```
repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git    
repo sync
```

The [wildartist site](http://www.wildartist.org/archives/1178) continues:

> If you encounter the message “command not found” then you can do it with the following commands:
>
> ```
> $ sudo sh /usr/local/bin/repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git
> $ sudo sh /usr/local/bin/repo sync
> ```
>
> It will take much time to get the code
>   even though the line is fast as the
>   project itself is really huge. After
>   the long waiting, you will find that
>   the checkout process has been ended.
>   The next thing to do is MAKE to build
>   the project. But you will meet a
>   message that the Java version is not
>   correct and the build process fails.
>   Then you can modify the
>   build/core/main.mk file to change the
>   text ”1.5″ to “1.6″.

At this point you should have the dependencies and the code take care of.  You will still need to `make` .

Because the code base and supporting libraries and components are changing, it's hard to keep the instructions perfectly up-to-date, which is why there are so many conflicting how-to's for this process.

Comment: I am afraid, It even doesn't work. My OS is 10.10 32 bit (processor 64bit arch). for the first command it is unable to locate: ib32z1-dev lib32ncurses5-dev also it can't locate ia32-libs.

Comment: @newcomer See if you can get these:  `sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf libsdl-dev libesd0-dev libwxgtk2.6-dev build-essential zip curl libncurses5-dev zlib1g-dev openjdk-6-jdk ant git-core gnupg flex bison gperf libsdl-dev libesd0-dev libwxgtk2.6-dev build-essential zip curl libncurses5-dev zlib1g-dev`

Comment: @jgbelacqua: liblz-dev install was successful and it says libncurses5-dev was installed before. So I need three more packages lib32readline5-dev libc6-dev-i386 ia32-libs (fyi I have jdk installed in my machine and I can run android app in emulator using eclipse)

Comment: Try `libc6-dev` and  `libreadline5-dev` . You won't need ia32-libs with your 32-bit OS.

Comment: Ok, everything installed. but when I try to initialize a repo client using: $ repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git it shows error **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mashruf/bin/repo", line 91, in <module>
    import readline
ImportError: No module named readline
**

Comment: Try running repo as `/usr/local/bin/repo` ?    Otherwise `sudo curl http://android.git.kernel.org/repo -o /usr/local/bin/repo` and then `sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/repo` and retry.

Comment: No. what does it mean by No module named readline?

Comment: I'm not sure what is in the repo script, but apparently it can't find the readline libraries.   Those should have been there with libreadline5-dev .   Here's another page that looks almost right-- has worked so far for my 32-bit sys: [android into ubuntu](http://www.wildartist.org/archives/1178)  .   
Exceptions are that the `chmod a+x` line there shouldn't have a `~` , and I used java6 instead of 5.

Comment: Yess!! I am downloading the source now and that is from 10.10. The readline Module was something from Python. My python installation was erroneous! Thank you for your nice editing here, Hope someone looking here will have a clear understanding

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to install some 32-bit packages which are not available in your repositories.You can not install i386 packages since your configuration is 64-bit.
Try finding similar packages in Synaptic package manager.For example search for libc6-dev and install suitable package for your system.

Comment: he is actually running a 32-bit OS.  I was also confused.

Comment: Yeah!I saw the update now.Fortunately it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: See jgbelacqua's answer. Getlibs should probably become a community wiki instead or something...

getlibs:

> getlibs /path/to/binary
>   getlibs -l i386librarytoinstall.so
>   getlibs -p i386packagename
>   getlibs -w www.website.com/i386package.deb
>   getlibs -i /home/chris/i386package.deb

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=474790

@Pedram: I'm afraid your answer is actually misleading.

Comment: Thanks for the nice link. But when I put $ sudo getlibs -w mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6-dev-i386_2.12.1-0ubuntu10.2_amd64.deb. It shows: **E: Unable to locate package mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc'**